# Let $U=${$xE | x$ in $ℝ^n$} and $E$ is $n\times n$ matrix, how would you show that the following is equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers

a) $E^2=E=E^T$  ($E$ is projection matrix)

b) $(x-xE)\cdot (yE)=0$

c) proj$^U(x)=xE$ $\forall x\in ℝ^n$

From a to b, it is pretty obvious by solving the equation and $xyE-xyE=0$

From b to c, since $xE$ is in $U$, that means $x-xE$ is in $U^\perp$, then by what theorem can you prove it?

From c to a, I have no idea what to write.

Could someone help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29

Answer (score 1):

(c)$\Rightarrow$(a):
Because for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x-xE\perp U$, $$(x-xE)E^Ty^T=0\quad\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$ This implies $E^T=EE^T$. Hence $$E=(E^T)^T=(EE^T)^T=EE^T=E^T,$$ which also implies $E=E^2$.

(b)$\Rightarrow$(c):
isn't this definition of $\mathrm{proj}^U(x)$?

Comment: Nice answer. Um, just a question, where does the $E^T y^T$ come from?

Comment: $(x-xE)\cdot yE=(x-xE)\times(yE)^T=(x-xE)E^Ty^T$.